# Insert Multiple Rows Into Temp Table With SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

These StackOverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676493/insert-multiple-rows-into-temp-table-with-one-command-in-sql2005), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part) all say the same thing, but I can't get it to run in SSMS or SQLFiddle

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Names
  ( 
    Name1 VARCHAR(100),
    Name2 VARCHAR(100)
  ) 

INSERT INTO #Names
  (Name1, Name2)
VALUES
  ('Matt', 'Matthew'),
  ('Matt', 'Marshal'),
  ('Matt', 'Mattison')
```

When I execute this is SSMS, the insert fails with the following message on the first line after `VALUES`

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

This [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32d8f/1) runs without the `#` sign, and the schema executes successfully when the table name is `#Names`, but I get the following message when I try to select * from the table

> Invalid object name '#NAMES'.: SELECT * FROM #NAMES

Does SQL Server 2012 support multiple inserts?

---

**Update**: Apparently accessing a 2005 server on SSMS 2012....

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION --Returns: Microsoft SQL Server 2005
```

Comment: Yes, SQL Server **2012** supports multiple inserts - makes me wonder if you have Mgmt Studio 2012, but you're really connected to a **2005** instance - what version do you get from `SELECT @@VERSION` ??

Comment: That's exactly it.  I'm connected to SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server **2012** supports multiple inserts - that feature was introduced in SQL Server **2008**.

That makes me wonder if you have Management Studio 2012, but you're really connected to a SQL Server **2005** instance ...

What version of the SQL Server **engine** do you get from `SELECT @@VERSION` ??

Answer (score 17):

When using SQLFiddle, make sure that the separator is set to GO. Also the schema build script is executed in a different connection from the run script, so a temp table created in the one is not visible in the other. This fiddle shows that your code is valid and working in SQL 2012:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d695/31)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
CREATE TABLE #Names
  ( 
    Name1 VARCHAR(100),
    Name2 VARCHAR(100)
  ) 

INSERT INTO #Names
  (Name1, Name2)
VALUES
  ('Matt', 'Matthew'),
  ('Matt', 'Marshal'),
  ('Matt', 'Mattison')

SELECT * FROM #NAMES
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d695/31/0)**:

```
| NAME1 |    NAME2 |
--------------------
|  Matt |  Matthew |
|  Matt |  Marshal |
|  Matt | Mattison |
```

---

Here a SSMS 2012 screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Now I wonder why it isn't working in SSMS.  I only put in on fiddle so other people could more easily replicate the issue.

Comment: See my update. The only thing I can think of is that you are connected to a 2005 instance.